# RatingBar enviando valor para TextView android

Tags: android

Boa tarde,
Como eu passo o valor de um RatingBar para um TextView direto sem utilizar clicks?

Comment: Pode explicar melhor?

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);   
ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(rating));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a chamada:

```
ratingBar.getRating();
```

Mas esse valor é um Float, ai é só converter pra String ou usar como Float mesmo.

Comment: Teria como bloquear para que o valor nao seja alterado sem ter que passar enable=false? Para que o usuario possa apenas ver o valor.

Comment: Eu costumo colocar o valor direto no xml:  android:rating="4"